# What is the difference in typescript variable exports

Tags: module, typescript, export

With typescript I can export the variable like that:

```
export var Stuff= mongoose.model<IStuffModel>('Stuff', Schemas.stuffSchema);
```

which can I import like that `import { Stuff } from '../models/stuff';`

or like that:

```
var Stuff = mongoose.model<IStuffModel>('Stuff', Schemas.stuffSchema);

export = Stuff
```

which can I import like that `import Stuff = require('../models/stuff');`

Also I realized that the imports approaches are not interchangeable.

So the **first** export won't work in case `export = Stuff` and the **second** won't work in case of `export var Stuff = ...`

Can anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone explain the difference

## Exports

### `export =`

This models the common JavaScript pattern of having the `export` at the bottom of the file. This is common to various module systems, here is an example for CommonJS/Node:

```
module.exports = {
   // something
}
```

### `export something`

This models the JavaScript pattern to export at point of declaration. Eg. in commonjs/Node:

```
module.exports.something = // something
```

## Imports

### Legacy

This is:

```
import Stuff = require('../models/stuff');
```

This is something that TypeScript added to allow the user to compile to `amd` or `commonjs` while using the same TypeScript code base. This is not recommended anymore.

### ES6

This is

```
import { Stuff } from '../models/stuff';
```

Standardized by JavaScript. This is just *one* of the patterns of import, here you have a *destructured* import.

## Avoiding the confusion

Just use the ES6 import/export syntax. This means don't do `export =` and don't do `import =`. Instead always `export something` and `import ... from ...`.